# Setting closure on other view controller with parameters

Tags: swift, closures

I have view controller A that presents view controller B as a popover. What I'm trying to do is to get a value that's set in view controller B, back in view controller A.

My thought is that I would accomplish this by passing in a closure that takes a parameter and having view controller B calling that with the parameter.

So, in VC A, I have:

```
func update(val:String) {
}
```

Then, when I create VC B, I tried:

```
bVC.notifier = update
```

but I'm getting error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '(String, String) -> ()' to type '() -> {}'
```

Then, in view controller B:

```
public var notifier = {}
```

then I'm not really sure how to call it.

I've read through: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94 but don't think it covered this situation very well.

Comment: *Remark:* you might want to check other mechanisms for achieving such a functionality, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3/40503024#40503024) (Alternatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, here's an example put together in a playground.  It uses simple objects rather than view controllers, but it should show the syntax required.

```
class A {
    func doSomething() {
        let myB = B()
        myB.notifier = { (s1, s2) in
            print("\(s1) : \(s2)")
        }
        myB.give()
    }
}

class B {
    typealias ReturnRoutine = (String, String) -> ()
    var notifier: ReturnRoutine?

    func give() {
        if let notifier = notifier {
            notifier("First", "Second")
        }
    }
}

let myA = A()
myA.doSomething()
```

Comment: I can use this and thank you. You did not specify using an existing function as the closure, though.

Comment: I believe it's a direct substitution as long as your function has a compatible signature, `func f(one: String, two: String)` in this case.