# Force error in guard statement?

Tags: swift, rest

I have a protocol that contains two functions `successWeather` and `errorWeather`. When the status code returns something other than 200-299 I want it to throw the `errorWeather` function.

My question is: How can I force an error if the guard catches the status code? As of now, error returns nil.

`func errorWeather(error: NSError)`

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            self.delegate.errorWeather(error: error as! NSError)
        }

        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
            print("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
            //How can I force an error?
            return
        }
```

Comment: It is kind of unclear -at least for me-, what's the relationship between the protocol and the throwable function? could you elaborate?

Comment: I basically created it as a delegate system to use the api. In a detailView it conforms to the protocol and has to use successWeather and errorWeather. @AhmadF

Comment: So, -if I got it right- what's the purpose of implementing both delegate and throwable function? I suggest to let it be only one option to handle the error. Is the problem of how you should implement the delegate or the throwable function? Also, you might want to check [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3/40503024#40503024).

Comment: @Casey could you check my answer

Comment: I recommend the Swift way: a callback closure returning an enum adopting the `Error` protocol with associated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSError` object encapsulates information about an error condition in an extendable, object-oriented manner. It consists of a predefined error domain, a domain-specific error code, and a user info dictionary containing application-specific information. more check  [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror)

```
 guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
                print("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
                //How can I force an error?
                let error = NSError(domain: "statusCode",
                              code: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
                          userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!"])

                    self.delegate.errorWeather(error: error )
                return
            }
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for linking the documentation!

Comment: It's my pleasure  mate