# Use of undeclared type 'UNUserNotificationCenter'

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

i want to show banner of  push notification when app is in foreground. And i implementing this method to show notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
```

but this error received Use of undeclared type 'UNUserNotificationCenter'
[image]

Comment: Have you added `import UserNotifications` ?

Comment: no let me import it

Comment: i am import error resolved  but yet do not received notification

Comment: import UserNotifications now this is working fine

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All you have to do is to import the [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework:

```
import UserNotifications
```

Also, make sure that you conforming to [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate).
As a good practice, I would suggest to do it by implementing it as an `extension`:

<sub>If you are unfamiliar with *Delegation*, you might want check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3/40503024#40503024) out.</sub>

```
import UIKit
// add this:
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    .
    .
    .

    // somewhere in your code:
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = delegateObject
}

// add this:
// MARK:- UserNotifications
extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```