# Is there something in Swift language equivalent to event listener in AS3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I'm looking for something similar to event listener in Swift, I want the function to be executed because I have socket to send every time it finds out a variable is not nil, the checking of the variable must be very frequent because I want live data to be received on the server. How could I do it?

Comment: "as3" stands for ActionScript 3?

Comment: Yes "AS3" is Adobe ActionScript 3

Comment: you could check the *delegation* pattern, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3/40503024#40503024). Note that the answer does include some of the patterns for letting objects talk to each other in iOS, in "Alternatives" section.

Comment: You can also use closure pattern, as function are the first class citizen in swift, you can declare them as property and use them as event listener.

Comment: Do you mean didSet?

Comment: Have you consulted the [Network Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html)?

Comment: Could someone give me a way to do this using delegation?