# How to pass outlet value of ViewContorller to its subView Swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, subview, pass-data

I am having ViewControllerA and a subView in the same ViewControllerA. I want to know how to pass outlet label  value of the ViewContorllerA to its subView.

Comment: If I got it right, you could do it by creating a [*delegate*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3/40503024#40503024) to your subview and pass the desired value by its methods. The mentioned answer contains "For Example" section which could be a good starting point to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm unable to get it. I got one outlet label in VC_A and it contains a subView. the thing is, suBView want's to know the value of VC_A label value. ( here subView is also in VC_A).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this method. I think this will be use full for you. Pass your outlet value here.

```
           let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryDescriptionViewController_id") as? CategoryDescriptionViewController

            destVC?.aTitleText = ""

            destVC?.aDescText = ""

            destVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            self.addChildViewController(destVC ?? UIViewController())
            self.view.addSubview((destVC?.view)!)
            destVC?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm unable to get it. I got one outlet label in VC_A and it contains a subView. the thing is, suBView want's to know the value of VC_A label value. ( here subView is also in VC_A).