# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am already new in Swift. I run app in simulator. I have list of books, when I click one of them, app shows details about selected book. When I click "Edit Book", change some details and click "Save Book" it paused on line 73

Where is mistake? Why delegate is "nil"? Thanks.

[image]

I create protocol and declare "delegate field as follows:

[image]

In DetailViewController, I set controller delegate as follows: [image]

Comment: you did not assign the delegate to anyone.

Comment: Show us also where you set the delegate...

Comment: @Ladislav I edit question.

Comment: This is only the declaration of the delegate variable, nothing gets assigned to the delegate here...where do you you have `delegate = something`?

Comment: @Ladislav I have no idea where delegate has been declared. In Main.storyboard delegate shown as Outlet which connected to Master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you implement `object.delegate = self` in the class that you want to conform to the delegate.

Also, I would suggest to implement the method calling by the delegate as:

```
delegate?.editBook(self, editBook: book)
```

it this case, nothing would happen if the `delegate` for some reason is `nil` instead of crashing.

Furthermore, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift/40503024#40503024) to make sure that you are setup the delegate as it should (probably, you missed the third step from the mentioned answer).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do as You suggested and it works. But it is difficult to understand what and why?

Comment: Glad to help. Have you checked the answer I mentioned?