# CollectionView pass data

Tags: swift, macos, uicollectionview

What is the correct way to pass data from my `ViewController` to my `CollectionViewItem`?

**ViewContoller**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {        
        let item = CollectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewItem
        item.themeName = getDirectoryContentByIndex(index: indexPath)
        return item
    }
```

**CollectionViewItem**

```
class CollectionViewItem: NSCollectionViewItem {


   var themeName: String!
   @IBOutlet weak var NameOfTheme: NSTextFieldCell!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do view setup here.
   }
}
```

Edit:
I want to assign the `themeName`as stringValue of `NameOfTheme`. But if I set the value, the IBOutlet is nil.

Comment: One way is to use Protocols and Delegates. Protocols and Delegates are used to talk from one class to another. You can learn how to use that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make fields of your cell `private` and make `configure(YOUR_PARAMS)` (in our case `configure(themeName: String)`. So in `cellForRow` you will call this function `cell.configure(themeName: "")`

Comment: Good idea. But it does not work for me. 
The problem is my `@IBOutlet weak var NameOfTheme: NSTextFieldCell!` is not set at the moment of pass the data. So i cant set the stringValue :(

Comment: @KennyWagenknecht I've never used `NSCollectionView`, but I think it's very similar to `UICollectionView`. You need to register cell type in correct way (here you are using xib file probably) - just google it. Make sure you associated file with `CollectionViewItem` right - again google will help you with those basic things. Then you can use it in the method above. Make breakpoints on awakeFromNib and other life cycle methods to be sure you're doing connections right