# How can I get a UIToolBar with buttons created from a view controller to another?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitoolbar

I am trying to create a second view controller and I would like to have the same toolbar with buttons that I created and coded from the first view controller without creating and coding that toolbar again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to create the toolbar in a parent view controller. You should use a navigation controller embedded in a **container view** for that.

This is the **scene structure** of this approach in Interface Builder:

[image: scene structure]

**View structure** (click to enlarge):

[image: view structure]

Use an **Embed Segue** to display the navigation controller in the container view.

[image: create embed segue from the container view]

[image: select Embed in the popup]

You can use delegates to pass actions (e.g. a bar button item was tapped).
[Read more about delegates in Swift here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift)

Comment: Yes, I rearranged my storyboard and codes. Finally, it worked! Thanks @the4kman