# Make calling ViewController accessible to called VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two VCs in my project. I have a UIButton that segues to the second VC. I have data being sent to this VC. I want the second VC to be able to add to the array that is sent and then send it back. 
In my main VC I have:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let toViewController = segue.destination as! SaveViewController
    toViewController.masterView = self
```

In the second VC I have:

```
var masterView:UIViewController!
```

...

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     masterView.listArray = listArray
 }
```

What I am getting is

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'listArray.'

The `listArray` is declared in both VCs. If this is a correct way to go about doing what I am trying to do, I am obviously assuming that I must do some more configuring in the second ViewController in order to make the other VC accessible.

Comment: `masterView` is a normal `UIViewController `, that doesn't contain a `listArray`. You should declare it with the type of your first UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is *not* the right way to pass data back the the previous view controller. Although there are other options that you can follow to achieve the desired functionality, I would recommend to follow the *Delegation* pattern approach.

For your case, you could do it like this -for instance-:

According to **"How to Apply Delegation?"** section in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift/40503024#40503024), the first thing that we should do is to implement the needed protocol:

```
protocol SaveViewControllerDelegate: class {
    // I assumed that 'listArray' is an array of strings, change it to the desired type...
    func saveViewControllerWillDisappear(_ listArray: [String], viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

Thus in `SaveViewController`, you should create -weak- instance of `SaveViewControllerDelegate` and call its method at for the desired behavior:

```
class SaveViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SaveViewControllerDelegate? = nil
    var listArray: [String]!

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // assuming that you already did the required update to 'listArray'
        // you would need to pass it here:
        delegate?.saveViewControllerWillDisappear(listArray, viewController: self)
    }
}
```

So far we added the necessary code for the `SaveViewController`, let's jump the the `MasterViewController` (first view controller):

Next, you would need to conform to `SaveViewControllerDelegate`, Connecting the delegate object and implement its method (steps from 2 to 4 in the mentioned answer):

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController, SaveViewControllerDelegate {
    var listArray: [String]!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let toViewController = segue.destination as! SaveViewController

        // make sure to add this:
        toViewController.delegate = self

        toViewController.listArray = self.listArray
    }

    func saveViewControllerWillDisappear(_ listArray: [String], viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("here is my updated array list: \(listArray)")
    }
}
```

At this point, `saveViewControllerWillDisappear` method should be get called when coming back from `SaveViewController`, including `listArray` as a parameter.

---

***Aside note:***

The reason of the error that you are facing is that you are declaring `masterView` as `UIViewController`, what you should do instead is:

```
var masterView:MasterViewController!
```

**HOWEVER** keep in mind that this approach still -as I mentioned before- *inappropriate* one.

Comment: ListArray was intended to be a multidimensional array of string arrays. I’ve looked deeper into this and I still am struggling to grasp delegates, but I am getting closer. Your answer did help quite a bit. I think I need a day or two to absorb the whole concept. Thanks.

Comment: @r405 don't hesitate to ask about any faced issue :)

Comment: I have a couple questions. after the SaveViewController class you put "UITableViewDelegate" as a parameter. Must this always be called when declaring a protocol/delegate? Also, am I correct in noticing that the protocol is declared in the main VC, as I see that its function is defined there? Just want to be thorough. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh actually it is a mistake, sorry about that :) Answer edited.

Comment: Alright just one more question. To store the updated array in the main VC, do I store it in a variable within the protocol? or is the function you provided making it accessible in the main VC already?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `UIViewController` has no element `listView`.

Change `MasterView` type to:

```
var masterView: FirstViewController!
```