# Change the value of a variable inside podfile from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, podfile

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

open class podview: UIView {
    open var strk = UIColor.black
    .
    .
}
```

I have to change the value of "strk" from another view controller. Is it possible to do it.

Comment: are you want to change in files that you have installed through cocoapods?

Comment: i am able to change it manually, but not by code

Comment: check access modifiers make it open and var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, You can do it. There are two way to do this.

1. Local Notification (NSNotification)

[NSNotificationCenter addObserver in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049020/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-in-swift)

2. Delegatation

[Examples of Delegates in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift/40503024)

3. If you want to Change View controller B Value from View controller A then you can directly access to it.

For EX ViewcontrollerB.yourVariable = Assign value - From View Controller A

Please review and understand both concepts.

Happy Coding..:)

Comment: This is not a view controller, podfile is a uiview

Comment: UIView is a child of UIViewcontroller. So, You can access it.

Comment: How can i change the value of variable "strk" . I have another variable called selectedColor which is a public variable. I have to make strk equal to selectedColor

Answer (score 1):

I'm just providing you trick.

Yes you can change it. First you need to `import` model of the pod.
then you need to create object of the `podview` and then you will be able to access `strk`  like

```
objectOfPodView.strk
```

Comment: I am able to access the variable, but the value of the variable is not changing