# How can I check popularProduct.xib file loaded into HomeViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, xib, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my HomeViewController have four section:

1. Banner
2. Popular Product
3. New Product
4. Old Product

All are `.xib` files and they are working fine.

Now I want to add `ActivityIndicator` in my `HomeViewController`

So now I want to show `ActivityIndicator` on `HomeViewController` until all the .`xib`'s file not fully loaded in `HomeViewController` as `.xib`'s `ActivityIndicator` should hide.

Now, the problem for me is that how can I get the confirmation about `.xib`'s loaded to `HomeViewController` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pretty simple direct solution, you could follow the ***delegation*** approach. So, when "Popular Product" View complete the needed process, you should fire a delegate method which will be handled by the view controller.

Example:

consider that in `PopularProduct` class you are implementing a method called `doSomething()` which need to get called and finish its work to hide the activity indicator from the view controller and it should send `Data` instance to the view controller. You could do it like this:

```
protocol PopularProductDelegate: class {
    func popularProduct(popularProduct: PopularProduct, doSomethingDidPerformWith data: Data)
}

class PopularProduct: UIView {
    // ...
    weak var delegate: PopularProductDelegate?

    func doSomething() {
        // consider that there is much work to be done here
        // which generates a data instance:
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: "...")!

        // therefore:
        delegate?.popularProduct(popularProduct: self, doSomethingDidPerformWith: data)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Therefore, in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
    var popularProduct: PopularProduct!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // show indicator
        popularProduct.doSomething()
    }
    // ...
}

extension ViewController: PopularProductDelegate {
    func popularProduct(popularProduct: PopularProduct, doSomethingDidPerformWith data: Data) {
        print(data)
        // hide indicator
    }
}
```

---

**Furthermore**, you could check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift/40503024#40503024) for better understanding for delegates.

Comment: will it work only for let data = Data(base64Encoded: "...")! what if if I have json data..

Comment: @SanjayMishra You could pass whatever you want :) depends on how you want to pass json. You could use `codable` and pass a model to the view controller.