# Unable to call another class method using delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, delegates

I'm trying to call method of Class B from class A on the button tap event. But it does not work and below is my code.

```
// Viewcontroller
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        var objA = A()
        objA.delegate?.TestA()
    }
}

// ClassA.swift
protocol TestA {
    func TestA()
}

class A {
    var delegate: TestA?
}


// ClassB.swift
class B : TestA {
    func TestA() {
        print(" Function A from b")
    }
}
```

When tapping a button, function TestA() does not invoke.

I even tried the code below, but it also didn't work:

```
var objB = B()
var objA = A()
objA.delegate = objB
```

Comment: You have not assigned anything to the delegate property of objA. Its nil. Thats why nothing is happening. Create object of class B. Assign it to delegate of class A object.

Comment: where is `var objB = B()` written??

Comment: This answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40503024/2370587

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of Delegates in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift)

Comment: On my machine, it works (if you set the delegate to `objB`). Will `btnClicked` be called at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you instantiate instance of Class A using

```
    var objA = A()
```

Clearly you haven't initialised `delegate` property in `A` because its optional its default value is nil

Now when you call

```
    objA.delegate?.TestA()
```

delegate is nil hence function TestA will not be called

**Suggestion**

Always use camelCasing for declaring names of functions. So `TestA()` is incorrect rather use `testA()`

**EDIT 1:**

Tested this

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let objA = A()
    let objB = B()
    objA.delegate = objB
    objA.delegate?.TestA()
}
```

This is working fine what is the issue?

Comment: @manisha-upadhyay: Thank you for accepting the answer, what was the issue ?

Comment: The **EDIT 1** above will work but does not benefit from defining the `protocol TestA`. This will work even when `class B` is not conforming to `protocol TestA`. See my answer bellow for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The objA.delegate is never assigned to an object, so it has an initial value of nil. The ? operator avoids calling a function on a nil object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Sandeep Bhandari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5706328/sandeep-bhandari) is right.

Some information for better understanding of Protocol and Delegates.
`TestA` is a `protocol` and an optional `var delegate` is defined in `class A`. This setup is right. The idea behind this setup is that any user of `class A`, in this case `class B` which conforms to `protocol TestA` gets a callback from `class A`. You need to call the `delegate.testA()` function from within `class A`. 
The current implementation of `ViewController` is not at all benefiting from defining Protocol and Delegates.

To achieve proper usage, the `class A` cab be modified as follows:

```
protocol TestA {
    func testA()
}

class A {
        var delegate: TestA?
        func process() {
            // Do something and call delegate function to report it.
            delegate?.testA()
        }
    }
```

And modify `ViewController` as follows (copied `class B` for completeness):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        var objA = A()
        var objB = B()
        objA.delegate = objB
        objA.process()
    }
}

// ClassB.swift
class B : TestA {

    func TestA() {
        print(" Function A from b")
    }
}
```

Now function implemented in `class B` to conform to `protocol TestA` will be called when `process()` function on `objA` of `class A` is called.
This is better use of Protocol and Delegate. Hope this helps.